# C# get all users emails and phone using my email account on company domain

Tags: c#, powershell, service, exchange-server

I need to get the list of users on a domain domain.com.it
using a C# windows application with my account on this

domain: my-account@domain.com.it
password: password

I tried C# exchange service, and power-shell

```
 Get-GlobalAddressList -ExchHostname mail.domain.com -UserName domain\username -Password Fall2016 -OutFile global-address-list.txt
```

On the Mail-sniper at GitHub 
but I got only the Email without Phone number.
I need to list the users data (Email, Full Name, Phone, .....) from anywhere.

Comment: Do some research on LDAP query. [sample](https://ldapwiki.com/wiki/LDAP%20Query%20Examples%20for%20AD)